# regress with a constraint/condition

Tags: command, regression, stata

I want to execute a regression but I need a condition/constraint in the command but mine doesn't work. My dependent variable is `COMP_STD` and my independent is `BGroup`. `BGroup` has the following values: `1` `2` `3` `4` `5`.

I want to run 5 different regressions with the variable `BGroup`, so that this variable equals 1, 2, and so on. This is the syntax that I tried:

```
regress COMP_STD if inrange (BGroup, 1)
```

but Stata says `inrange not found` so I guess it has to be another syntax which I can't find.

Comment: `inrange()` shouldn't be presented as `inrange ()`. It needs three arguments, e.g. `if inrange(BGroup, 1, 1)`. But `if BGroup == 1` is simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much Nick! I tried this command too but I think I misspelled something, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that `regress` is irrelevant here as the problem is entirely about selecting observations.

Comment: @NickCox would you like to post your answer as yacc proposed?

Comment: Does anyone know if a condition like is allowed in a multiple regression?

Comment: Naturally; do try it. (Frankly, these are beginner's questions, and Stack Overflow isn't really aimed at beginners. You are expected to read documentation _carefully_ and to try out code for yourself.)

Comment: Everytime before I post a question I try it on my own and try to look for solutions on my own but I have to admit that it is hard for me as I am a beginner and don't know much about statistic programs like stata so I ask for help and I'm really thankful for any advice!

Comment: @GiuliaMariaWagner If you are ok with Nick's answer, accept it, unless you want to wait for better or more answers. If you find it helpful, give it an upvote. :)

Comment: @yacc i already did that

Comment: @NickCox There are tons of beginner questions here. If the question is clearly stated then there's no need to withhold an answer.

Comment: @yacc The site explains itself as for professional and enthusiast programmers and the criteria for good questions include showing research effort. I don't know how much Stata you know but I know enough to assure you that this question is not one I would expect to see from either group.  Specifically, the documentation for `inrange()` makes an answer evident. Clearly, I did reply, but my comment is I believe consistent with how SO explains itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't want do spread any outrage but I just don't know who or where to ask if I stagnate at any point of my analysis which I calculate for my bachelor thesis. If you don't want to answer just don't but I got taught that it costs nothing to ask..

Comment: There's no outrage here. Every site or forum has its own expectations and style. Here is one standard for SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (Naturally, I follow your advice: I don't answer if I don't want to.)

Comment: @NickCox I didn't intend to start a dispute over this. Thank you for helping out here, since I don't know anything about stata (I also upvoted your answer ^^).

Comment: @yacc Thanks for that indeed (including the upvote). As yet the OP doesn't have enough reputation to upvote, I think. What it boils down to is that people can and will draw the line in different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inrange()` shouldn't be presented as `inrange (`*whatever*`)`, i.e. with a following space. There is a hint that Stata can't understand you; otherwise why is it asking about `inrange`? The reason for that puzzlement is that --when separated from its arguments -- a bare `inrange` looks like the name of a variable (or scalar), and you have no such variable (or scalar).

You didn't get that far, but the `inrange()` call was illegal for another reason. It needs three arguments, e.g. `if inrange(BGroup, 1, 1)`.

But `if BGroup == 1` is much simpler.

Note that `regress` is irrelevant here as the problem is entirely about selecting observations. That said, `statsby` is a command possibly useful here for getting several regressions at once.